# Unwanted 1 second black background show

Tags: android

I have one activity and others are fragment. When I click the `btnMain`, I want to clear the backstack and display the `MainActivity`. I can clear the backstack and can go to `MainActivity` class but my problem is that there is a 1-second (one second) showing of black background before going to `MainActivity`. How could I fix it ? Below is my code `onClick` of my `btnMain`.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnMain = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMain);
    btnMain.setOnClickListener(this);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.btnMain:

    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);//for clearing backstack
    overridePendingTransition(0,0);

    default:
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put your code of `MainActivity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what worked for me is to hide and show the views.they are in the same layout with distinct ids and when home button is clicked, I just hide the other one and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the activity is going to play activity creation animation from the blank background. Recommended workaround is to add `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);`

The code would be as below.

```
case R.id.btnUnreadNotif:

Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);//for clearing backstack
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION); // newly added.
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
break; // Do NOT miss this code :)

default:
    break;
```

if the code works same as before, please place the line `overridePendingTransition(0,0);` to the above on the `setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

Comment: still the same output.